# Repeated DNS not found error

Tags: dns

I have a domain from godaddy and server on Amazon ec2. From past month we have been getting DNS not found error which resolves itself after 5 - 10 minutes. Sometimes if we remove www from the url it works and other time if we add www then it works. Our customers are also facing this issue so its not a problem with our service provider

I have no clue where to even start to resolve this (im from StackOverflow you see). Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you used any of the DNS tools online to check the DNS?  I have no affiliation with http://www.dnsstuff.com/ and it spits out a good report

Comment: @Steve thanks for that. That's some start. let me try and fiddle with suggested settings

Comment: You say *we*. Who is we? You? Could it be your ISP? Are your DNS records being hosted where your statement of authority (SOA) record is? It could be that no authoritative answer is available and a non-authoritative answer is provided. The problem with this is, non-authoritative answers can be unreliable. These can come from cache or an ISP DNS, anywhere.

Comment: @closetnoc by we i mean my team of tech. and i do not understand your second question

Comment: Every domain name has an SOA (statement of authority) record that declares that the DNS is the authority for the domain. The domain name records should be on this DNS. Generally, this is the registrar DNS. Sometimes people try and reconfigure their DNS with their host and something is not right. Make sure that your registrars DNS is the SOA or only has NS records pointing to the SOA and that your records are all defined on the same DNS as the SOA.

Comment: @closetnoc , so i checked in dnsstuff.com and i am getting this message for SOA "No nameservers provided an SOA record for the zone. You should configure your nameservers to have a master slave relationship. The update of the zone information to the slave nameservers should be handled through the SOA record." Can you help in how to fix this

Comment: I do not know how your DNSs are configured, but this message seems to match what I am thinking. When a users browser does a DNS query and no authoritative answer is available, then a non-authoritative answer will be used. The problem is, if only non-authoritative DNSs are available, then the results can be unreliable or no results given and you get the errors you are seeing. You are likely adding your DNS records with your host when your registrar is your SOA. Add your DNS records with your registrar then the problem should go away. Stop using the host unless this breaks things. Cheers!!

Comment: Are you using Amazon Route 53, Godaddy, or some other DNS host?   You posted details about your registrar and your web host, but the details that matter most about your DNS host are omitted.